# Host up and running , but service reference cannot be created from client

Tags: wcf

I have a console app that is hosting the service by WCF's ServiceHost object, but from the client cannot add the service reference and I am getting the following error:

```
The URI prefix is not recognized.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 
'net.tcp://localhost:8001/Alu'.
There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://localhost:8001/Alu 
that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address 
or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution 
and adding the service reference again.
```

I have also activate the WCF Non-Http stuffs in the control panel. Where should be looked into the address this issue?

Comment: Run the service and check its address

Comment: Are you sure there is a service with the endpoint address 'net.tcp://localhost:8001/Alu running? Have you entered the correct Metadata address and  have your app.config well configured?[https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ec8429cc-387c-4bdd-ac59-69b37313d730/wcf-help-needed-metadata-contains-a-reference-that-cannot-be-resolved-nettcplocalhost](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ec8429cc-387c-4bdd-ac59-69b37313d730/wcf-help-needed-metadata-contains-a-reference-that-cannot-be-resolved-nettcplocalhost)